# react-router-dom: go back twice in history on go back event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, react-router-dom

I have three  components *C1, C2, C3* mapped on routes `/c1`, `/c2/`, `/c3`.

I want to prevent component `C3` from allowing (via browser event handling) going back to `C2` and instead go directly to `C1`.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: This functionality is required because C2 acts as a "post-and-redirect". Imagine cases where browser performs a POST operation, and when you refresh the page it asks you if you want to resubmit the form. Well that's exactly my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This functionality is required because C2 acts as a
> "post-and-redirect". Imagine cases where browser performs a POST
> operation, and when you refresh the page it asks you if you want to
> resubmit the form. Well that's exactly my case.

In this case you can redirect in the flow to maintain the history stack you desire. In doing so then any back navigation (imperative/declarative from code or browser's back button) results in going back to the correct page you want the user to go back to.

| Action | History Stack | Path | Back Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| initial | `["/"]` | `"/"` | ~ |
| PUSH "/c1" | `["/", "/c1"]` | `"/c2"` | `"/"` |
| PUSH "/c1/c2" | `["/c1", "/c1/c2"]` | `"/c1/c2"` | `"/c1"` |
| REPLACE "/c1/c3" | `["/c1", "/c1/c3"]` | `"/c1/c3"` | `"/c1"` |
| POP (1) | `["/c1"]` | `"/c1"` | `~` |

To use imperative navigation in `react-router-dom`:

- v5 use the `useHistory` hook

  - use `history.push` for normal navigation
  - use `history.replace` for redirecting
  - use `history.back` or `history.go(-1) to go back a page
- v6 use the `useNavigate` hook.

  - use `navigate(to)` for normal navigation
  - use `navigate(to, { replace: true })` for redirecting
  - use `navigate(-1)` to go back a page