# Clear all history in react-router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

Let's say you have two pages, signin page and home page. Home page is only available when you are logged in. When you visit the site, you are directed to signin page and sent to home page once authenticated.

Once a user is signed in, I want them to not go back to signin page. The back button should be greyed out.

I know for this case, you can use `navigate('/homepage', { redirect: true })`. But what should I do for a more complicated authentication flow?

All I can think of is to clear all history when a user is finally authenticated and redirected to homepage.

Comment: Using redirects is the way to navigate to new pages and not muddy up the history. What exactly is the issue you are trying to resolve? Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70251004/8690857

Comment: @DrewReese As you know, using redirects does not allow going back. I want users to navigate back and forth during the authentication flow, but once they are signed in and sent to the homepage, I want to block back button as if it's the first page. I know this is not the typical way of building user experience, but I am building a RN app that has WebView in it. In an app you dont want to go back to the sign in page once you are signed in.

Comment: Certainly redirects allow back navigations, they don't block it. I think I see what you are saying, but without any [minimal, complete, or reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's rather difficult to make any suggestions. Each specific use case might have its own specific solution, depending on needs.

Comment: @DrewReese Right. Excuse me for not clarifying how redirects work. For now, I can't spare time to generate the reproducible code. I just wanted to know if there is a method in react-router that clears up the history stack. Guess there isn't! Thanks Drew.

Comment: store the current user in the session and check whether is there any user logged in! in the sign up page onload function. if yes redirect to home page.

Comment: On home page load check is there any user currently in session if no redirect them to sign up page

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing I'm aware of in `react-router` or `react-router-dom` that clears the entire history stack.